# How to get many values from same input box and assign them to variables?

Tags: c#, .net

I have 4 buttons: `button_1` writes in the `InputBox` the number 1, `button_plus` writes in the same `Inputbox` `+`, `button_2` writes the number 2. Finally stands in the `Inputbox`: `1 + 2`.

Now, I want to use the `button_Equals`, to get `1 + 2` from the `Inputbox` and assign them to a variable. I used `int.Parse()`, `Int32.Parse()` and `Convert.ToInt32()` to get both numbers 1 and 2:

```
r = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
s = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
```

I'd like to assign 1 to `r` and 2 to `s`, but the program collapses when I click on the `Button_Equals` and it shows the following message:

> System.FormatException

Comment: Did you look at what is being passed to `int.Parse`? Check that it really can be parsed as an `int`, as if not, you'll get this exception. On a general note, you should always use `TryParse` to check your input, which would avoid this sort of problem. If you're still having trouble, post more code, as there isn't really much here.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you write them to the input as text and then try to parse that text? It's much better and easier to assign them to variables while you're writing them to the input, and then use the values directly from the variables.

Anyway, if you really want to parse the text in the input, you've got to first remove the `+` sign and then split the two values. Something like this:

```
var x = textBox1.Text.Split('+');
s = int.Parse(x[0]);
r = int.Parse(x[1]);
```

Comment: i tried this:  private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Operation.Equals("+"))
               //var x = textBox1.Text.Split('+'[]);
            s = int.Parse(textBox1.Text[0]);
            r = int.Parse(textBox1.Text[1]);

            textBox1.AppendText(" = " + (s+r));
        } but it doesnt work

Comment: Don't share code in comments, it's very hard to read. Of course that code will not work, it has many errors and makes no sense. You cannot use `textBox1.Text[0]` because the value is string not array. You can have to use `x[0]` like in my answer. The same goes for `x[1]`.

Comment: I cant use the variabl x... var split is new for me and as i typed it, it showed error… should i add an answer when i want to write a Code in the Forum?

Comment: What error are you getting? And what version of .Net are you using? Don't type anything, just copy the three lines of code in my answer and paste them replacing your two lines. It seems you typed `z` instead of `x` the two last lines. As for your other question, you only add an answer if it is an answer. If you only want to provide more info, edit your question and add the info.

Comment: is there any other keyword, which we could use. My Lehrer meant the keyword var we dont use :( –

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `var` in this context, but you can use `string[]` instead. So the line becomes `string[] x = textBox1.Text.Split('+');`. The compiler will produce the exact same result in both cases.